# make Custom Shape Button - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I programmatically create a custom `UIButton` like parallelogram or diamond and change every side of button size?

Buttons should be like these diamonds (maybe parallelogram):

[image]

Comment: May you please share an image and some more details about what you want?

Comment: Sure, I shared the final UI.

Comment: Whatever you see visually on screen, their frame (the position and size relative to the superview) are rectangles. You can start from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are lot of ways to create custom controls like buttons, slider, switch, etc. You can follow this [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/411-core-graphics-tutorial-part-1-getting-started) for more details.

Example:

```
let customButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 140.0))
customButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

let aPath = UIBezierPath()

aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 0.0))

aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 40.0))
aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 140))
aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 140))
aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 40.0))

aPath.close()

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.path = aPath.cgPath

customButton.layer.addSublayer(layer)

self.view.addSubview(customButton)
```

Source : [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html) has more shapes by default and you can make your custom shapes as well.